# Not saving information in the database in Mongodb mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, orm, nestjs

I have a problems module, in the service, when I want to save a DTO, the data is not saved

create method:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProblemsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Problem.name) private ProblemModel: Model<Problem>,
    @Inject('USERS_SERVICE') private readonly client: ClientProxy,
  ) {}
  async create(createProblemDto: CreateProblemDto): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const username = this.client.send(
        'findByUsername',
        createProblemDto.creator,
      );

      if (!username) {
        throw new BadRequestException('Username does not exist');
      }

      console.log(createProblemDto);

      const problem = new this.ProblemModel(createProblemDto);
      await problem.save();

      return problem;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

When I send this data:

```
{
    "title": "hello",
    "description": "world",
    "creator": "john_doe"
}
```

This is how it is stored in the database:

```
{
    "_id": "658ef5bdf8ed34a05abcad94",
    "ideas": [],
    "__v": 0
 }
```

and this is my schema:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';

export type ProblemDocument = HydratedDocument<Problem>;

@Schema()
export class Problem {
  @Prop()
  title: string;

  @Prop()
  description: string;

  @Prop()
  creator: string;

  @Prop()
  ideas: string[];

  @Prop()
  createdAt: Date;

  @Prop()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @Prop()
  deletedAt: Date;
}

export const ProblemSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Problem);
```

- The connection to the database is established.
- The data in the DTO is valid.

Why my data is not saved in database and how can I fix this issue ?